# ASP.NET MVC running multiple instances of the same webpage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an application that utilizes WebAPI to communicate to a WCF service. I have recently decided to utilize ASP.NET routing so that I can have an easier URL link to navigate to instead of navigating to a specific .html file. I currently have it set up to instead route to my controller which then returns my html file. My problem is when I run multiple instances of the new URL (e.g. copy localhost:port to another browser tab) it copies data from my input text fields on each tab. If I type "John" in the first tab while both tabs are open, now the 2nd tab contains "John" as well. How should I go about preventing this? I would like to be able to run the application in any number of tabs.

I am using VueJS within my javascript so I initially thought it might be caused by the binding nature. However, I tested this in a blank ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application and the same problem occurred if I put a textbox in the .cshtml file. To me it seems like all the URL links are pointing to the exact same html file (almost like a pointer to it). The code below is from my from scratch .cshtml file with an added input element.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
    <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building...</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Getting started</h2>
    <p>Testing</p>
</div>
</div>

<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Mickey">
```

I expect to be able to type in the first tab's input field and the 2nd tab's input stays blank.

Comment: This is probably "Browser Link".  Try turning it off in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Amy this was it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Amy was correct in that it was a browser sync setting. You can find this in the Quick Launch (ctrl + Q) in Visual Studio. Once you find it turn "Enable form sync" to false.